# Is there any way to test the highcharts with large data-set with Jest and React.?

Tags: unit-testing, highcharts, performance-testing, large-data, react-highcharts

I am trying the write test for highcharts.
But how to test the highchart with larger data set, to check the performance and to test if highchart works with larger data set.

Library  : Highchart-react-official, Jest, React

Answer (score 2):

I usually use Chrome Dev Tools / lighthouse for benchmarking javascripts / browser performance which can be automated using nodejs module:

[image: Chrome Developer Tools JavaScript profiling]

For chrome dev tools see: 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools

For lighthouse see: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/lighthouse#javascript_boot-up_time_is_high

PS: Depending on the browser and device you are testing on you'll see different performance. So it's best to use a controlled system in a dedicated VM (rather than local machine where other processes, software and tabs might affect performance at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts React Wrapper contains tests for: testing environment, chart rendering and passing down container props.

API: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#tests